# Word for describing moderate movement speed

Tags: word-choice

What word can be used to describe moving at a moderate pace?

1. Moving `Slowly` describes slow speed.
2. Moving `Quickly` describes fast speed.

I am looking for the best **single word** replacement. Moving `Moderately` is what comes to mind but doesn't satisfy me very much.

The context is to have a list of words from which a user can choose the best adverb to describe the speed of a moving object.

**Detailed Context**
Working on a software tool for a person to use while monitoring video. In this software they will be able to assign different speeds to a "target" (not a person and not alive). I need to have a list of adverbs they can choose from (thus the reason for a single word, otherwise the list will look funny and be too complicated).

Comment: Can we get a bit of context? Out-of-context, *moderately* or *normally* could work.

Comment: Moving _steadily_ implies no haste but no dawdling.

Comment: I think *moving at a moderate pace* might be less ambiguous than *moving moderately*.

Comment: To me moving steadily (while it has some connotations with speed) refers more to whether the pace is changing or not.

Comment: Note that *Slowly* and *Quickly* are not adjectives.

Comment: @Jim I changed to adverb. Also, I agree `moving at a moderate pace` is less ambiguous but I need a single word replacement.

Comment: @bizzy For what purpose do you need a single-word replacement?  Context could help us figure out what word would fit best.  Also, why does it *need* to be a single word?

Comment: *in normal speed*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Low speed
- Medium speed
- High Speed

This is simpler than trying to find a midpoint word between "slow(ly)" and "quick(ly)".  This is the terminology you would see on a three-speed kitchen mixer, or a three-speed hair dryer.

Actually, on the speed-control labels these are often shortened to:
- LO,   MED,   HI

Comment: I decided that the adverbs were complicating things too much. This does the trick just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something between slow and fast, you can try ***[Average](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/average)***

> A number expressing the central or typical value in a set of data, in particular the mode, median, or (most commonly) the mean, which is calculated by dividing the sum of the values in the set by their number:
>   the proportion of over-60s is above the EU average of 19 per cent

or ***[Medium](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/medium)***.

> The middle quality or state between two extremes; a reasonable balance:
>   the song soon discovers a happy medium between thrash and catchy pop

Answer (score 0):

**intermediate** (*adj.*): coming between two things in time, place, character etc.

**intermediately** (*adv.*)

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intermediate)

Although not specifically related to the speed of movement, the term indicates a midpoint between **slow** and **fast**. If you are building a drop-down list, you could enter field values as the adjectival forms.

I have substituted the term **quick/ly** with **fast**, as the former:

...applies particularly to something practically instantaneous, an action or reaction, perhaps of very brief duration: *to give a quick look around; to take a quick walk.*

The latter refers to:

...actions, movements etc., that continue for a time, and usually to those that are uninterrupted; when used of communication, transportation and the like, they suggest a definite goal and a continuous trip.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick) [*see: Synonyms*]

Answer (score -1):

I would use *unhurriedly* or *deliberately*.

Comment: Welcome to the ElU :-). Your answer would be more helpful to the OP and the future users of the website if you added dictionary definitions and/or examples of usage with references, for your suggestions. Thanks!